# Pandas cannot write to excel sheet

Tags: pandas

`dftcr_hv_tv_tth5.to_excel('C:\Users\alemthottg\Desktop\KiTTEN-TAQ\PlyCluster\tcr_hv_tv_tth5.xlsx',sheet_name='NewSheet',encoding='utf-8')`

The Error message I am getting.

> File "", line 3
>       dftcr_hv_tv_tth5.to_excel('C:\Users\alemthottg\Desktop\KiTTEN-TAQ\PlyCluster\tcr_hv_tv_tth5.xlsx',sheet_name='NewSheet',encoding='utf-8')
>                                ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated
>   \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Does adding `r` before filename solve the problem? (like this: `r'C:\Users\alemthottg\Desktop\KiTTEN-TAQ\PlyCluster\tcr_hv_tv_tth5.xlsx'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create an ExcelWriter first.

```
# create an ExcelWriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\alemthottg\Desktop\KiTTEN-TAQ\PlyCluster\tcr_hv_tv_tth5.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dftcr_hv_tv_tth5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewSheet', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: # create an ExcelWriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"C:\Users\alemthottg\Desktop\KiTTEN-TAQ\PlyCluster\tcr_hv_tv_tth5.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
dftcr_hv_tv_tth5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewSheet', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
writer.save()

Comment: Thanks to George for the correction (r'...' makes the path a raw string and avoid escaping backslashes). The above code was edited accordingly, but still not really tested.